# Socket-based communication is independent of a programming language used for implementing it. How is it possible?

Tags: java, c++, sockets

I understand that Socket-based Communication is independent between programming languages. Which means, a socket program written in Java language can communicate to a program written in C or C++ socket
program. And I've see many similar questions like mine in Stack overflow and I appreciate those answers.
But I didn't get what I'm looking for. Can anyone answer this with example code as JAVA program as a Server and C++ program as Client which runs on different machine and how they communicate?

Thank You :)

Comment: It's not clear what you don't understand. As asked, the question is way too broad.

Comment: In the end, it's all just bytes being sent and received. There are various ways to write the code. The programmer just has to setup the logic so that the bytes are being used for the same meaning in each application.

Comment: @David Sehwartz I just wanted to know how JAVA and C++ programs on client/server side  understand each other

Comment: @TheUndeadFish Thank You for your help. Now It's making sense to me

Comment: @KishoreKumarNaidu The same way they can read, display, and understand the same image files. They follow some protocol or specification that specifies what bytes go where.

Comment: Keep in mind too that each application - in whatever language - is calling down to the same OS routines supporting socket communications... they just have to provide the function parameters, including pointers to the byte data involved and various structures that must be properly populated with address data etc..  But, it's not much different to calling any other "
"native" OS routines.

Answer (score 1):

Socket communication is basically sending a set of bits (data/packet as you would call at a higher level) from one port to another. Port is nothing but a file/IO stream that can listen to data or send data given the correct address. A valid address is a combination of valid IP address(depending on if you want local or remote communication) and port number.

To answer your question we basically are opening a file, writing or waiting to be written into from another application. So, file open, close, read, write has nothing to do with a programming language. Only thing that varies between different languages are the APIs or interfaces provided to achieve this purpose.

When you open a socket you mention about the protocol you want to use for this communication, it could be TCP/UDP based on the purpose of your application. The protocol decides how the packet/data being sent and received are ordered. Basically, trying to establish a common ground between the 2 parties trying to communicate.

Hope this answer helps!!