# Can a C++ uWebSockets server communicate with a JavaScript client?

Tags: javascript, c++, websocket

There are a few things I don't understand about [uWebSockets](https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets), but mainly, does uWebSockets work with normal WebSockets, or is it just borrowing the name? I've been scratching my head for a few days and I have no idea if I'm doing something wrong or if I'm just dumb.

I've made a bare minimum server in C++ that starts correctly as far as I can tell -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <uWS\uWS.h>

int main() {
    uWS::Hub hub;

    hub.onConnection([](uWS::WebSocket<uWS::SERVER> *ws, uWS::HttpRequest req) {
            std::cout << "A client connected" << std::endl;
        }
    );

    if (hub.listen(13049)) {
        std::cout << "Listening on port 13049" << std::endl;
        hub.run();
    }
}
```

Along with a basic JavaScript client -

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:13049");

ws.onopen = function(event) {
    console.log("Connected");
};
```

So my question. Why doesn't this connect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer!

`hub.listen("0.0.0.0", 13049)`

I realized that I could only connect to the server with localhost and I just couldn't understand why. After looking around at some other WebSocket articles, I found the problem. It's because, by default, the server only tries to accept a connection from localhost. I don't know why that would be, but you have to manually tell it that you want to listen to everyone.

To do this, instead of just `hub.listen(13049)`, which would only be accepting localhost, I would put `hub.listen("0.0.0.0", 13049)`. "0.0.0.0" is a way to say "any address". This fixes the problem and allows me to connect normally from any WebSocket.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the title: Yes. Sockets are structures to send and receive data via specified ports and addresses. They are **independent of programming language**.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_websocket.htm

I don't know if this link has all covered up, but after you initialize a socket, you still need to put one side to listen (this one you did at the server) and another to **send** infos.

This is an elegant way to say that you're not connecting because you didn't connect. Everything as expected.

Good studying!

Another thread about that issue:
[Socket-based communication is independent of a programming language used for implementing it. How is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26987071/socket-based-communication-is-independent-of-a-programming-language-used-for-imp)

Comment: Thanks for the input, however the WebSocket constructor does send the request to connect if I'm not mistaken. The code I've provided should work.

Comment: Okay, that does answer part of my question, thanks. Now I just need to figure out why my code doesn't work.

Comment: I've just had a breakthrough, actually. Changing 127.0.0.1 to localhost seems to have made a difference and the client can connect now. Any ideas on why this is?